# Applying styles to an element with a class based on both the parent div's class and its previous sibling's class

Tags: html, css

Consider the following example:

```
 <div class='parent'>  
      <a class='goodchild'>I am good</a>  
      <p class='child'>..</p>  
    </div>
```

and

```
 <div class='parent'>  
      <a class='badchild'>I am bad</a>  
      <p class='child'>..</p>  
    </div>
```

Now I want to apply  different rulesets for the two examples(say give the first example's 'child' class a margin of 10px and the second example's 'child' class a margin of 20px). Using CSS how would I define the rules which taken into account the previous sibling's class i.e 'goodchild' or 'badchild' and the parent class 'parent'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: Try [adjacent siblings selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) to target nearest sibling element

```
.parent .goodchild + .child {
    margin:10px;
}
.parent .badchild + .child {
    margin:20px;
}
```

### [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/v9z7qe9a/1/)

Comment: I don't know why this answer is downvoted but it works. Thanks =)!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that using "Adjacent Sibling Selector" (`+`).

```
.goodchild + .child {
    margin: 10px;
}
.badchild + .child {
    margin: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.parent .goodchild{
   margin:10px;
}

.parent .badchild{
   margin:20px;
}
```

This should work.

Comment: I believe you didn't understand what the OP wants. He wants to apply the margin to the `.child` div inside each of the `.parent` div's.

Comment: as Fahad pointed out, your answer does not target the .child class